# Use ng-model with label element.

Tags: angularjs

I am reading a code and got into a part where a label element is been used with data-ng-model is that possible ?

```
<label class="btn btn-success"
  data-ng-model="myController.statusFilter"
  data-btn-radio="'disabled'"
  data-ng-click="myController.method()">
  Disabled
 </label>
```

Comment: Why you want to bind model with label?

Comment: It is the btn-radio directive that transforms it to a 'radio button'. Probably this one: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons

Answer (score 13):

It wont't work. Since ngModel should only be used with the **inputs**, since it involves two-way data binding.

Label does not deal with user input, thus it does not require the ngModel. So if you want to bind a scope variable to the label then you can use **[expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)**.

Like

```
<label>  {{labelText}} </label>
```

*Note : you should define labelText in your controller, like `$scope.labelText = "Hello"`*

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `ng-bind` example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6fkpk4NnshvMYvtumTmC?p=info).

Answer (score 2):

```
<label class="btn btn-success"
  data-ng-bind="myController.statusFilter"
  data-btn-radio="'disabled'"
  data-ng-click="myController.method()">
  Disabled
 </label>
```

in this case ng-bind will work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 app.directive("editable", function ($document) {
        return {
            scope: {
                text: "=ngModel"
            },
            restrict: 'A', 
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                element.text(scope.text);

                scope.$watch('text', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue != oldValue) {
                        if (newValue != element.text())
                            element.text(newValue);
                    }
                });

                element.on("keyup", function (event) {
                    scope.text = element.text();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
 <label editable="true" contenteditable="true" ng-model="value"></label>
```

Answer (score -3):

No, because it would not serve any purpose. What would the model affect? How would you affect the model when it was bound to the label?

If you are instead attempting to update the text inside the label, you should just put a variable in your template:

```
<label class="btn btn-success"
    data-btn-radio="'disabled'"
    data-ng-click="myController.method()">
  {{ myController.statusFilter }}
</label>
```