# using model value directly or passing as a parameter to function from view to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using both the solutions but not sure which one is better in technical terms.

1. I can pass a model value from front end HTML to a function i.e. calling a function ng-click

**View:**
`<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-click="clicked(name)">`

**Controller:**

```
$scope.clicked = function(name){
var param = name;
}
```

**OR**

**View:**
`<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-click="clicked()">`

**Controller:**

```
$scope.clicked = function(){
var param = $scope.name;
}
```

both solutions work but I wonder which one is better. In my opinion, the first solution gives more readable code by showing that which parameter is passing to a function and where it is being used.

Comment: You can not define model for label.just for tags such as `input` ,`select` and other

Comment: Kindly refer this : [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435491/use-ng-model-with-label-element)

Comment: You should try to bind models and click events on input elements for a correct semanthic and readibility. What is the context for using a label with a ng-model? Regardeless the fact, i think second is more angular way, but the function name is not representative, maybe something like `<label model="name" ng-click="clickLabelForFooReason()">` works

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have put this question to understand the technical concepts of both solutions. I have changed the question from label to input type (that was not the suppose to be questioned).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I try to pass least params possible.

If the value can be known in controller level, such as in your ccase, then I won't pass it.

I only pass when using say `ng-repeat` for the controller to differentiate which item I clicked.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clicked(item)"></div>
```

Comment: got you point because using ng-repeat, we need to get the selected item from the loop. but what if pass the parameter always? does it cost the process?

Comment: I think it doesn't make a lot of difference. More like personal preference?

Comment: I also try to declare least scope params as possible, I try to use `var` if a param doesn't need to be exposed in the template.

Comment: True. least declaration of $scope is good but in my question, there is not extra declaration of $scope variable. It is either you access the $scope directly or through parameter of method.

Comment: There has to be some break point if you want to pass in, let's say your function is to save name, phone, address of a user, do you pass in all 3? What if you need to use the array of states, do you pass in as well?

Comment: Got you point but i am trying to know the cost of it. if i send an object array i.e. save(array) and then take it as array.Name, array.City in controller.